# timber context filter inside add_shortcode function

Tags: wordpress, timber

I've been trying to access timber context in add shortcode function but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is 
       add_action( 'init', array($this, 'create_shortcodes' ) );

```
public function create_shortcodes() {
  add_shortcode( 'social_media', array($this, 'social_shortcode') );
}

public function social_shortcode($atts) {
  $params = shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => 0
  ), $atts);


  $data = Helpers::create_social_media( $atts['id'], false, true );

  add_filter( 'timber_context', array($this, 'add_to_context_social_media'), 11 );

  return \Timber\Timber::compile('social-media.twig', array('data' => $data['content'] ));
}

public function add_to_context_social_media($context) {
    echo '<pre style="margin:200px">';
  print_r($context);
  echo '</pre>';

  return $context;
}
```

If I add the filter inside the create_shortcodes function it works, but it doesn't isnide the add_shortcode function which also is inside the create_shortcodes function.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to render the returned output instead of rendering it inside the shortcode ?

```
$returned_shortcode = do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');

return \Timber\Timber::compile('social-media.twig', array('data' => $returned_shortcode ));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this line

```
add_filter( 'timber_context', array($this, 'add_to_context_social_media'), 11 );
```

Then you would need to call `Timber::get_context()` for the filter to be applied. However, calls to `Timber::get_context()` are cached. This means that if you wanted to use the `timber_context` filter, you’d have to do add it before your first call to `Timber::get_context()`. If you wanted to use that in a shortcode, you probably already call `Timber::get_context()` in the singular or archive PHP template that displays the post’s content.

I guess you could build up the data context for your **social-media.twig** template like follows:

```
public function social_shortcode($atts) {
    $params = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 0
    ), $atts);

    // Get cached context.
    $context = Timber::get_context();

    // Add to context.
    $context['data'] = Helpers::create_social_media(
        $atts['id'],
        false,
        true
    );

    return \Timber\Timber::compile( 'social-media.twig', $context );
}
```

In addition to your custom `data`, you would also have the global context available in your Twig file.